# Add openmp shared variable to a fortran mpi code

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp

I have a MPI Fortran 90 code that parallelises a grid of points N on Np processors (knowing that N=n*Np).

Each processor calculates a vector of size N/Np. This allows to do some calculations on that portion of the grid.

Sometimes the 0 process outputs a vector of size N in which it collected all the N/Np vectors calculated by each process (in order). I know how to do this.

I now need to collect that same vector but not only on the 0th process but on all processes and not only sometimes but every time step to do a new different calculation.

For the moment I'm using the same code but without the "if process 0". However this takes a lot more time because all processors need to share their vector with all other processors.

A college told me about OpenMP and how it has options to have "global" variables. I would like to have a vector of size N that can be access by all processors and rewritable by the corresponding section of the vector by all processes.

First of all. Is it possible/simple to use both OpenMP and MPI in a code? And second how can i create such a "global" variable?

Comment: You cannot use OpenMP to implement shared memory across MPI processes. OpenMP onl works for threads inside one single MPI process. You have to use the memory sharing and messaging techniques from MPI to communicate between MPI processes.

Comment: Remember that every time you replicate data on a process your code becomes inherently non-scalable. Thus the question should not be "how do I do this more efficently/simply", it should be "can I reorganise things so I don't need to do this at all"

Comment: @VladimirF I talked to my supervisor yesterday after posting this question. He told me the same, it will be easier to just use MPI_ALLGATHER, with the downside that this will add a little of simulation time.

Comment: You can use OpenMP to make the processes in the MPI job themselves parallel. Instead of having N MPI processes per node, you can have one MPI process per node which uses OpenMP to make use of all the node CPUs. This will decrease the time complexity of most collective operations, including `MPI_ALLGATHER`.